# When should I up / down vote

Tags: discussion, voting

This question is at a stack exchange meta level
The alt text for up voting a question is `this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear`. Should the question be useful to me or if i think it would be useful to other people?

Answers are even more confusing, I am suppose to vote depending only on whether the question is 'useful' or not. Without taking into account if it's correct or not, is it clear etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out ["When should I vote"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote/130054#130054). It's more specific to Stack Overflow, but it should give you an idea.

The aim of SE is to provide Q&As that will  be searchable and useful to a large amount of people. So, if you feel that a question is well researched, on topic and asking for omething that others will find useful, upvote it. Similarly, if you feel that an answer is substantiative and/or very helpful (not to mention *correct*), upvote it.

However, your votes are yours, the above is just a guideline. Feel free to set your own standards, most of us vote pretty freely.